# Is there a simd instruction/intrinsic/builtin for partial shift of elements?

Tags: c++, gcc, x86, sse, simd

A minimal example would be more beneficial:

Say I have a sorted 8 ints = `{10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80}` (My use case is for sorted integers but i am not sure if that information is valuable considering vector instruction act on the entire dataset)

There are few operations required:

1. Insert and shift.

-> insert 25 at it's sorted location.
-> becomes insert 25 at index 2 and shift rest.

`10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80` becomes: `10, 20, 25, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70`

2. Remove and shift and insert at back.

-> remove 20 from the array and insert 90 at back if 20 is found and removed.
`10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80` becomes `10, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90`

Or would a set of instructions make it work?

I am trying the insert and shift part with multiple steps for a descending sorted array. https://godbolt.org/z/_WCxkW

Comment: There's AVX2 `vpermd` for 256-bit vectors, and SSE2 `pshufd` for 128-bit vectors (of dword elements), which could move other elements to set up for a `vpblendd` to insert one.  There's nothing particularly efficient, though, and no good way to turn an insert-position into a shuffle control vector.; if you're trying to build a SIMD sort, insertion-sort within a SIMD vector is not good.

Comment: By `int` you mean `int32`? Do you store 8 of them inside two SSE registers? Or do you use `int16`? Also: Signed or unsigned? Or do you have AVX2 available? How do you determine the to-be-removed object (by value or by index)? If it is determined by value, what shall happen if the element does not exist? And if you insert a zero at the end, after removing, your array won't be sorted anymore.

Comment: Int32. Currently I am not directly handling SSE registers, mostly working through OpenMP. `> Also: Signed or unsigned?` Whatever works, values are inherently unsigned. `> Or do you have AVX2 available?` I do.`> How do you determine the to-be-removed object (by value or by index)?` Search by value on sorted array. As I said, need to remove `20` from the array in the example.
`> If it is determined by value, what shall happen if the element does not exist? `
Nothing. Array remains as is.

Comment: @chtz `And if you insert a zero at the end, after removing, your array won't be sorted anymore.` Basically a sentinel value, which I can replace later.. Ideally it's a remove and insert at the back. so, `10, 20,30,40` if i remove 20, then next number would be greater than 40.. say input 50 so it becomes `10,30,40,50`. I will edit the example in the question

Comment: Is your array actually stored in memory? (That would simplify shifting, by just loading from an offset-address). What shall happen if a to-be-removed number exists multiple times? Also, "do nothing", if elements does not exist makes this slightly more complicated -- I'd have a relatively straight-forward solution for "remove the first element not smaller than `x`" (or the last not greater -- which is equivalent if `x` exists exactly once)

Comment: SIMD vectors don't efficiently support the kinds of operations you're asking for; what problem are you *really* trying to solve?  You should probably attack the high-level problem a different way.

Comment: @PeterCordes You don't think maintaining a sorted vector might be efficient for a btree? (Granted it varies a bit in that there could only be 1 duplicate).

Comment: @Noah: Oh, yeah that's a use-case where this might actually be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One general approach to do what you want is (the general idea is the same for `[u]int_{8,16,32,64}` or even `float`/`double`):

Insert `x` into `input`:

```
// Shift your input array (e.g. "abcefghi") to the right:
out = ShiftRight(input); // out = 0abcefgh
// broadcast the to-be-inserted element (e.g., 'd')
insert = broadcast(x); // insert = dddddddd
// compute 
out = min(max(out,insert),input)
//  == min(max(0abcefgh,dddddddd),abcefghi)
//  == min(ddddefgh,abcefghi) == abcdefgh
```

Remove first element not smaller than `x` from `input`:

```
// shift input (e.g., "abcdefgh") to the left (insert something at the end)
out = ShiftLeft(input); // out = bcdefghX
// determine elements smaller than `x` (e.g., "f") by broadcast and compare
mask = broadcast(x) < input; // mask = 11111000
// take masked elements from `input` and other values from `out` (using a blend instruction)
out = blend(mask, input, out); // == abcdeghX
```

If the number of elements to be removed is not guaranteed to be 1 (i.e., it may not exist or exist multiple times), this is more difficult, since every output value potentially depends on every input value. One idea might be to compare for equality and count the number of elements (using a `maskmove` and `popcount`).

---

For shifting you can use

- SSE2 and only one 128bit register: [`pslldq`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PSLLDQ.html), [`psrldq`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PSRLDQ.html)
- SSSE3 and a sequence of 128bit registers: [`palignr`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/palignr)
- AVX2 and one 256bit register: [`vpermd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpermd:vpermw) with a pre-determined index vector (there is no AVX2 equivalent of the previous instructions which works over the entire 256bit register)
- If your input is stored in memory, load it again with one element offset (this requires a "safe" element beyond each end of the array -- and it may introduce a significant write-read latency if you perform these operations multiple times)

For broadcasting, I suggest just using the `_mm[256]_set1_epi32` intrinsic and let the compiler figure out what is most efficient (without AVX2, this will likely require a shuffle)

Min/max operators exist for various sizes/types (depending on the SSE/AVX version) -- just search for instructions starting with `pmin`/`pmax`.

As far as I know, there are no unsigned comparisons before AVX512, but of course you can use signed comparison, if no values are bigger than the biggest signed value. Or you can workaround by flipping the upper bit before comparing (I assume there is a related question on stackoverflow).

Finally, blending is done by [`pblendvb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pblendvb) if you have SSE4.1. Otherwise you need to do some bitwise-and/andnot/or operations.